# Enviar dados de um GridView em um Form para ComboBox em outro Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou tentando enviar os dados de um `gridview`num segundo `Form`para uma `combobox`no `form` principal mas não tenho obtido sucesso. Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de fazer isso sem que seja enviando como parâmetro, uma vez que irei chamar o `form`principal em outros momentos sem precisar deste valor.
Segue código da tentativa:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.cbComputador.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
    this.Close();
}
```

Preciso que o valor apareça imediatamente na `combobox` "Computador" quando o usuário der os dois clicks.

Comment: No caso dos parâmetros você pode deixa-lôs como Opcional, ja atribuindo um valor a ele tipo no contrutor por exemplo public 
       Form2(int? cbComputadorSelected = -1){
       }
Ao atribuir ao combo você valida se há valor na variavel tipo cbComputadorSelected > -1 .. Vc atribuiria o index.. Sendo assim você pode chamar o form principal em outras vezes sem ter de informar este parametro por ser Opcional

Comment: Pode por favor exemplificar com trecho de código e adicionar como reposta à pergunta?

Comment: Montarei um exemplo para postar

Comment: Já o fizeram kkk

Comment: Agradeço a atenção assim mesmo...

Comment: @DLopes Conseguiu resolver o problema? A resposta atende o que foi pedido ou precisa que melhore em algo?

Comment: Foi de grande ajuda. Já marquei como resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça de uma maneira em que este parâmetro não seja mandatório para o funcionamento do *form* ou então crie uma propriedade pública no segundo *form* que receberá este valor.

Exemplo:

1. Parâmetro opcional

   ```
   // construtor
   public Form1(int? valorOpcional)
   {
       if(valorOpcional == null)
           // Nenhum valor foi passado
       else
           cbComputador.SelectedIndex = (int)valorOpcional;
   }
   ```
2. Com a propriedade

   ```
   public class Form1
   {
       public int? ValorDoCombo { get; set; }

       public Form1() 
       { 
           if(ValorDoCombo != null)
               cbComputador.SelectedIndex = (int)ValorDoCombo;

       }
   }
   ```

   E o uso seria algo como

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       Form1 form = new Form1();
       form.ValorDoCombo = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
       this.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Eu consigo receber o valor corretamente, mas ao utilizar "cbComputador.SelectedIndex = (int)pc;" (sendo pc minha variável opcional) ele exibe o erro "Value of 'X' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'." (sendo X o valor que tiver sido selecionado).

Comment: Bom, isso é porque o valor utilizado não é um index válido. Não tem como responder melhor sem ter mais detalhes. A implantação da resposta está certinha, é algum problema ao capturar o valor (talvez uma confusão entre index e value?). Você pode abrir uma nova pergunta com este problema também...

Comment: Um outro detalhe importante que não adicionei à pergunta é que inicialmente o valor do ComboBox é preenchido com dados de uma tabela do meu BD

Comment: Se eu utilizar SelectedValue ao invés de SelectedIndex nada acontece. Ele não exibe nada, a não ser os valores iniciais do BD

Comment: Como eu disse, sem mais detalhes é difícil. Abre uma nova pergunta com todas as informações necessárias.