# Resolver erro Value of 'X' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex', sendo X qualquer valor de Index

Tags: c#, combobox

Olá.
Fiz uma pergunta dias atrás sobre capturar o valor de uma célula de um `gridview` em um `Form` secundário e envia-la para um `combobox` no `Form` primário. Recebi uma reposta satisfatória e que faz com que o `Form` primário receba o valor, entretanto quando tento mudar o índice do `combobox` para o índice que recebi a mensagem de erro **Value of 'X' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'**, sendo X o valor recebido.
Vale ressaltar que ao iniciar a aplicação este mesmo `combobox` cbComputador é preenchido com dados de uma tabela do BD, conforme código. Gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de resolver este impasse.
Código de preenchimento do `combobox`:

```
public DataTable GetIdentificador()
    {
        DataTable dataUf = new DataTable();
        bdConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=controle;uid=root;pwd=''");
        try
        {
            bdConn.Open();
            if (bdConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                //Se estiver aberta faz a consulta dos dados do BD
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT identificador FROM computador WHERE status=0", bdConn);
                dataUf.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            bdConn.Close();
            bdConn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Impossível estabelecer conexão.\n" + ex.Message);
        }

        return dataUf;

    }
```

Quando carrego o `combobox` com os valores do método acima:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbComputador.ValueMember = "identificador";
        cbComputador.DisplayMember = "identificador";
        cbComputador.DataSource = GetUF();
    }
```

Link da pergunta que fiz anteriormente com a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210811/enviar-dados-de-um-gridview-em-um-form-para-combobox-em-outro-form). No caso, estou utilizando a primeira opção dada na resposta.
Caso não tenha sido claro o suficiente, favor comentar que tento explicar novamente com mais detalhes.
Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente acontece que o valor retornado da GridView não deva ser um Indice existente no combobox.

O retorno do valor dessa coluna é realmente um index ou seria um Identificador de cada UF?

```
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value
```

Caso seja um Identificador, como eu imagino que seja deve ser utilizado o '**SelectedValue**' ao invés do '**SelectedIndex**'

Comment: Quando utilizo o **SelectedValue** ele não muda o que está sendo exibido no combobox

Comment: Parece que o valor se perde, uma vez que se eu inserir um `gridview` no mesmo Form e executar a mesma linha com **SelectedValue** ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando a resposta aqui publicada juntamente com a resposta deste [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/a43a9173-2eb4-403a-8089-7af420149742/chamar-metodo-ou-objeto-de-outro-form?forum=vscsharppt). Espero que ajude a mais alguém.